# Are there more ways to select keywords in a column than 'select' method?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I've am currently using the 'select' method to perform a search for a specific keyword in a column. Following that, I would print out the entire row of information.

```
require "csv"
alarms = CSV.read('alarms.csv')
high = alarms.select { |level| level[0] =~ /high/ }
puts high.inspect
```

I am new to ruby and was wondering if there is another method to do this?

1)
[image]

2)
[image]

3)
[image]

Comment: Didn't you already do this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661396/select-function-on-a-column-in-csv-using-ruby.

Comment: yes, I couldnt get an answer, so I thought of re-phrasing my question under a new category. Would greatly appreciate for some positive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alarms = CSV.read('alarms.csv', :headers => true)
highs = alarms.select { |alarm| alarm[3].to_i == 1 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: @ItamarG3 Will that mean that people would read an answer without reading OP's question?

Comment: @RAJ most certainly. people find the questions through google. they usually skip the question and read the accepted answer.

Comment: @ItamarG3 Then the one who writes the answer is not responsible for the reader's irresponsibility.

Comment: @RAJ in fact you are. If you want your answer to be _useful_, then an explanation would do the trick.

Comment: @ItamarG3 We are here to give the banana, we are not here to peel the banana for them to eat.

Comment: @RAJ [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/). those are generally what are expected from answers.